# How to generate a grid 2d graph in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, graph

I'm trying to represent a graph like this in Python:

[image: Graph]

The basic algorithms is the following, but I have to consider separately cases, where the indices of the vertex are out of the graph's range.

```
G = {(i, j): [(i-1, j), (i, j+1), (i+1, j), (i, j-1)] for i in range(0, n) for j in range(0, n)}
```

Then I can add 4 loops + 4 cases for the corners of the graph, or iterate through the graph above and filter out the bad cases. What's the most elegant solution?

P.S. I can't use non-standard libraries. The answer, where the graph is represented with a list of lists, where each row index is the number of the vertex and it's value are the nodes it's connected to would be even better.

Comment: @EnesErdogan I said that I can't use non-standard libraries. What else code do you need? That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using control flow statements to check conditions when populating the list of neighbors or filtering neighbors are both fine approaches -- my natural inclination is to make all possible neighbors and filter them, it might not be the best idea for really huge graphs.

This could be done as a function, but just in case you need to have additional types of graphs or need additional functionality (like some method that returns whether two points are connected) you might as well start a class, here's just one example of how you might do that:

```
import typing
import itertools

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 shape: typing.Tuple[int, int],
                 connectivity: str = "grid"):

        self.nodes = {} # type: typing.Dict[tuple, list]

        self.shape = shape
        self.connectivity = connectivity

        self._init_nodes()

    def _init_nodes(self):
        # iterate through all combinations of coordinates
        for x, y in itertools.product(range(self.shape[0]), range(self.shape[1])):

            # switch in case there are other connectivity types, but for this example just grid
            if self.connectivity == "grid":
                # make and all possible neighbors
                neighbors = [(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)]
                # filter impossible neighbors
                neighbors = [n for n in neighbors if 0 <= n[0] <= self.shape[0]-1 and 0 <= n[1] <= self.shape[1]-1]
                self.nodes[(x,y)] = neighbors
                    
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError('only grid for now!!!')
```

Which gives a dictionary of connected nodes as you have in your OP, though i'm not quite sure if this answers the question b/c can't tell what you're asking for in the last paragraph (my bad), so let me know if not:

```
>>> a_graph = Graph((5,5))
>>> pprint(a_graph.nodes)

{(0, 0): [(1, 0), (0, 1)],
 (0, 1): [(1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)],
 (0, 2): [(1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 3)],
 (0, 3): [(1, 3), (0, 2), (0, 4)],
 (0, 4): [(1, 4), (0, 3)],
 (1, 0): [(0, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)],
 (1, 1): [(0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)],
 (1, 2): [(0, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3)],
 (1, 3): [(0, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4)],
 (1, 4): [(0, 4), (2, 4), (1, 3)],
 (2, 0): [(1, 0), (3, 0), (2, 1)],
 (2, 1): [(1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)],
 (2, 2): [(1, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)],
 (2, 3): [(1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4)],
 (2, 4): [(1, 4), (3, 4), (2, 3)],
 (3, 0): [(2, 0), (4, 0), (3, 1)],
 (3, 1): [(2, 1), (4, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2)],
 (3, 2): [(2, 2), (4, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3)],
 (3, 3): [(2, 3), (4, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)],
 (3, 4): [(2, 4), (4, 4), (3, 3)],
 (4, 0): [(3, 0), (4, 1)],
 (4, 1): [(3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)],
 (4, 2): [(3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3)],
 (4, 3): [(3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)],
 (4, 4): [(3, 4), (4, 3)]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess adding ifs/additional loops is the only way

Comment: There could be some way to do it in a single line, but that's pretty discouraged in Python and then you don't get all the fun and useful bonuses of writing a class <3. An interesting programming challenge though :)